# Is there a bug in IE on Windows Phone 8.1 where a page enters a reload loop?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, reload, windows-phone-8-emulator

I can't really give minimal repro for this, so apologies if the question is deemed too localized. I don't have a WP device, but when using Browsertack with any Lumia, [this page](http://stampsy.com/plastiglass-journal) enters an infinite reload loop.

This neither happens on desktop browsers (including IE), nor on other mobile browsers. I can't see if the issue is localized to WP, or if it's a bug in emulator. This doesn't happen in desktop IE's “emulating” mode either.

What could be causing this?

Comment: I don't have a Lumia handy, but I don't see any obvious errors running that page in IE on an HTC 8x with the Windows Phone 8.1 developer preview 8.10.14219.341

Comment: @Rob thanks, I actually already fixed and it and will follow up. Problem was due to false negative on Modernizr pushstate support check due to WP 8.1 user agent changes. Appreciate the response!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was due to [Windows Phone 8.1 user agent change](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869301(v=vs.85).aspx) that now includes `Android 4.0`. This caused a [false negative in Modernizr's History API support check](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/1471), which in turn caused react-router to use `window.location` instead of `pushstate`, and refresh the page on every `replaceWith` call.

Comment: This is fixed in react-router 1.0.0-beta5 and later: https://github.com/acdlite/redux-router/pull/183